# "Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject'" when linting my podspec

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am trying to create an update for the [jre_emul podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/jre_emul), as version 0.7.2 is outdated now.

Using the original podspec file I learned a lot about the podspec format. With the update though, I am trying a different approach: I want to use the binary distribution of J2ObjC as a source for the podspec.

The current state of the podspec including the used sources can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/chendrak/jre_emul).

When I try to validate the podspec from the repository, I get the following errors:

```
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/NSObject+JavaObject.h:31:12: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/NSObject+JavaObject.h:49:4: error: expected a type
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/NSObject+JavaObject.h:51:4: error: expected a type
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/NSObject+JavaObject.h:60:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSObject'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/IOSArray.h:31:34: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSCopying'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  jre_emul/include/IOSArray.h:31:23: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'IOSArray'
```

If I remove the "jre.source_files" line and add the header files to the "jre.preserve_paths" line it validates correctly since no files are being compiled.

I can use that podspec in another project, but I have to manually add the "jre_emul/include" dir to the Header Search Paths, which is not desirable in my opinion.

Comment: `pod --version` should be `0.23.0`. On this newest version this spec lints perfectly for me.

Comment: @KeithSmiley
I have 0.23.0 as well. You did lint the podspec from [my repository](https://raw.github.com/chendrak/jre_emul/master/jre_emul.podspec) and not the one is the master repo, right? The one from the master repo works for me as well, but the source behind it is outdated.
If that works for you, any other ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: oh sorry, yes I'm seeing similar errors to those that you showed. These are all build errors which means there's an issue with the source and not your spec (at least in this situation). I would clone the project and try to fix any issues you see in Xcode